# Replace enclosing Apostrophs with HTML tags but not inside <code> blocks

Tags: php, regex

**Goal:** Modifying an HTML string that contains apostrophs for wrapping code inline (like Stackoverflow is doing it). But the same time having `<code>` blocks that can also contain apostrophs which should stay unchanged.

**Example:**

```
<p>This is my `inline code`, it can be replaced and tag-wrapped.</p>
<p><code>This text contains `apostrophs`, but should `not` be changed.</code></p>
```

This regex I am using for converting all wrapping apostrophs to <code> elements:

```
// replace apostroph with incorporating <code> tag
$content = preg_replace('/(.+?)\`(.+?)\`/', '$1<code class="inlinecode">$2</code>', $content);
```

**Required:** 

Change the regex, so that it does *not* convert the apostroph if it is withing a `<code>` block.

*Disclaimer: I tried for several hours to read the HTML string, use PHP's DOM parser, extract all nodes of type `code`, change their content, write them back, then found out that nodeValue is removing all HTML tags (especially the line breaks). Then tried several solutions found online, still not working... Now I am falling back to regex, even against the odds.*

*FYI, how I tried it the DOM way:*

```
$code_blocks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('code');
foreach($code_blocks as $codenode) {
// nodeValue strips HTML tags, we need to hack
$nodevalue_html = $codenode->ownerDocument->saveXML($codenode);
// replace, i.e. custom-store each apostroph with '~~~APO~~~' so that they survive
$nodevalue_html = preg_replace('/`/', '~~~APO~~~', $nodevalue_html);
// $codenode->textValue = $nodevalue_html; // fail
// $codenode->nodeValue = $nodevalue_html; // fail
// ...
}
// html to string
$html_new = $dom->saveHTML();
$html_new = preg_replace('/~~~APO~~~/', '`', $html_new);
```

I wished I could use Markdown like Stackoverflow, but I still need to deal with HTML.

Comment: Could you share an html string to reproduce the problem with DOMDocument.

Comment: This is the dummy example I am working on: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ah52kmuw/5/

Comment: If you want to easily indent inside code tags, you can remove br tags and enclose code tags between pre tags. http://www.jsfiddle.net/ah52kmuw/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way is to explode and reassemble the string:

```
$html_string = '....................'; // contains apostrophes and <code>...</code> blocks

$delim = "<code>";
$closing_tag = "</code>";
$explode = explode($delim, $html_string);

foreach($explode as &$ex) {
    $closing_tag_pos = strpos($ex, $closing_tag);
    if ($closing_tag_pos !== false) {
        $pre_closing_tag = substr($ex, 0, $closing_tag_pos);
        $post_closing_tag = substr($ex, $closing_tag_pos);
        $ex = $pre_closing_tag . preg_replace('/`/', '~~~APO~~~', $post_closing_tag);
    }
}

$mapped_html_string = implode($delim, $explode);
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. For the code, could it be that the `$ex = ...` part is instead: `$ex = preg_replace('/`/', '~~~APO~~~', $pre_closing_tag) . $post_closing_tag;`?

Comment: Implemented your solution into our forum, the parsing seems to work: https://www.stacklounge.de/2351/kann-man-from-in-sql-mit-zwei-tabellen-verknupfen 

Comment: Great! I suggested this approach because I work with strings that don't follow any set pattern but DO have a rule that needs to be respected (similar to your situation) - I always need to explode->map->rebuild. Remember that the implode() step can is time-expensive if the string is large and the process is repeated many times

Answer (score 1):

Using an XPath query to avoid text nodes that have a `code` element as ancestor:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xp->query('//text()[not(ancestor::code)][contains(.,"`")]');
foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
    $parts = (function($text) { yield from explode('`', $text); })($textNode->nodeValue);
    $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    do {
        $frag->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($parts->current()));
        $parts->next();
        if ( $parts->valid() ) {
            $codeElt = $dom->createElement('code');
            $codeElt->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($parts->current()));
            $frag->appendChild($codeElt);
            $parts->next();
        }
    } while ($parts->valid());
    $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $textNode);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/Ro6VS)

[demo for php < 7.0](https://3v4l.org/W5FRm)